# VS Code simple console Journal program issue

Tags: c#, class

First year student working through a class project. When running the main program after entering the menu selection 1 in the console, the program stops running. I have coded each of the following classes in it's own cs file, main program file code is provided at the bottom.

PromptGenerator class code

```
using System;

public class PromptGenerator {
public List<string> Prompts {get; set;}

    public PromptGenerator() {
        Prompts = new List<string> {
            "What was the best part of your day?",
            "Write about an experience where you felt the spirit with you today:",
            "Who was the most interesting person you interacted with today?",
            "Write about something that happened for which you are grateful today:",
            "If you had one thing you could do over today, what would it be?",
            "What was the strongest emotion you felt today?",
            "Write about an act of service you either witnessed or performed today:>",
            "Write about something you learned today:",
            "Write about a tender mercy you noticed today:",
            "Write about a positive interaction you had with someone else today:",
            "Write about something you noticed that reminded you of Jesus Christ today:",
            "Write about something you learned about someone in your life today:",
            "Write about an experience you had that allowed you to teach someone else today:"
        };
    }

    //Generates a random prompt from the list
    public string GenerateRandomPrompt() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(Prompts.Count);
        return Prompts[index];
    }

}
```

Entry class code

```
using System;

public class Entry {
public string DateCreated {get;}
public string Content {get;}

//Initializes the date and content of an entry from user input
public Entry (string dateInput, string content) {
DateCreated = dateInput;
Content = content;
}

    //Displays the content of an entry
    public void DisplayEntry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Date: {DateCreated}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Content: {Content}\n");
    }

}
```

Journal class code

```
using System;

public class Journal {
public List <Entry> entries;
public PromptGenerator promptGenerator;

    //Constructor initializes and empty list of entries
    public Journal() {
        entries = new List<Entry>();
        //Initializes the prompt generator
        promptGenerator = new PromptGenerator();
    }

    //Adds a new entry to the journal from user input
    public void AddEntry() {
    
        string prompt = promptGenerator.GenerateRandomPrompt();
        Console.Write("Please enter the date(mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        string dateInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Today's Prompt: {prompt}");
        Console.Write("> ");
        string content = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //Displays data input this session
    public void DisplayEntries() {
        foreach (Entry entry in entries) {
            entry.DisplayEntry();
        }
    }

    //Saves Entries to a file named by the user
    public void SaveToFile() {
        Console.Write("Please enter the filename you would like to save to: ");
        string filename = Console.ReadLine();
        try {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename)) {
                foreach (Entry entry in entries) {
                    writer.WriteLine($"{entry.DateCreated}\n{entry.Content}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Journal entries saved to {filename}");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving entries to {filename}: {e.Message}");
        }
    }

    //Loads Entries from a file named by the user
    public void LoadFromFile() {
        Console.Write("Please enter the file name you would like to load from: ");
        String filename = Console.ReadLine();
        try {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                    string dateString = reader.ReadLine();
                    string content = reader.ReadLine();
                    Entry entry = new Entry(dateString, content);
                    entries.Add(entry);
                }
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error loading entries from :filename: {e.Message}");
        }
    }

}
```

Main program code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
        //Creates a new instance of Journal
        Journal journal = new Journal();

        //Welcome banner
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Your Daily Journal!");
    
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add Entry");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Display");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Load");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Save");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Quit");

            //Requests user selection for action to take
            Console.Write("Please select an option (1-5) ");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            //Calls class methods per user selection
            switch (choice) {
                //Adds new entry
                case "1":
                journal.AddEntry();
                break;

                //Displays added entries
                case "2":
                journal.DisplayEntries();
                break;

                //Loads entries from a file
                case "3":
                journal.LoadFromFile();
                break;

                //Saves entries to a file
                case "4":
                journal.SaveToFile();
                break;

                //Exits program
                case "5":
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
                return;

                //Handles invalid input
                default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection, please enter a number 1-5.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What changes would I need to make to allow the program to run as expected?

I've tried running the debugger and it has the same issue with no error thrown. I've tried xperimenting with the syntax of the calls for the promptGenerator class and GenerateRandomPrompt method, as well as the AddEntry method. The program should run the main menu, and act as commented per menu selection, but instead the program simply exits, when the user makes a selection from the menu.

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `switch` in `Main`. Examine the string that was read. Assuming it is correct and will match one of the cases step into that code and make sure it does what you think it should. Narrow down the problem.

Comment: I have copy/pasted your code and successfully run the project.  I see the menu, enter 1, it prompts me for the date, displays today's prompt, and after I've responded, I'm back at the main menu.  This would suggest your problem may not be with the code itself-- recommend you use the debugger to step, line by line through the code.  Put a breakpoint on the switch statement, and step.  Also I'd recommend putting a breakpoint  on each of the closing braces, to check for unexpected exits before the program closes.  Hang in there, you can expect a career in programming to be filled with debugging!

Comment: Also, what IDE are you using?  Perhaps try and run your project, using 'dotnet run' from the terminal.  See if the result is any different.

Comment: If using VScode, firstly check a .vscode folder was created alongside your project, containing a launch.json.  If not, from the command palette, choose, ".NET: Generate assets for build and debug".  Then, inside the launch.json, be sure "console" is set to "integratedTerminal".  Refer to-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: That AddEntry method prompts for inputs but does not actually add them.

Comment: You may also want to use Random.Shared instead of creating a new instance for each prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually had to use the dotnet build and run methods in the terminal to be able to fix the run issue, and have also addressed issues with the code (the AddEntry not adding, no case for 3 and 4 and LoadFromFile not actually displaying the loaded content) I just needed another set of eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nuance with VScode:

"The Debug Console doesn't accept terminal input for a running program. To handle terminal input while debugging, you can use the integrated terminal (one of the Visual Studio Code windows) or an external terminal."

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code

You can simply run your program using 'dotnet run', or if you require the debugger, be sure to modify the launch.json asset, to set the "console" option to "integratedTerminal".

If your project doesn't have a .vscode folder containing the launch.json, you can open the command palette and run this command: ".NET: Generate assets for build and debug".